# Shared edge between two geojson polygons

Tags: javascript, geojson, geometry, turf

I am interested in getting the coordinates of a shared edge (if exists) between two geojson polygons. I am (currently) using turfjs and geojson-equality libraries

I tried this but I consider it quite inefficient

```
function sharedEdge(poly1, poly2) {
    for (p1=0;p1<poly1.geometry.coordinates[0].length-1;p1++)
        for (p2=0;p2<poly2.geometry.coordinates[0].length-1;p2++) {
            var point1 = turf.point(poly1.geometry.coordinates[0][p1])
            var point2 = turf.point(poly2.geometry.coordinates[0][p2])
            var point3 = turf.point(poly1.geometry.coordinates[0][p1+1])
            var point4 = turf.point(poly2.geometry.coordinates[0][p2+1])

            if ((equality.compare(point1,point2) && equality.compare(point3,point4))
                || (equality.compare(point1,point4) && equality.compare(point3,point2)))
            {
                    return [point1,point3]
            }
        }
    return false
}
```

Is there a shorter/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the turf.js [intersect](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_intersect.html) function.

According to the API docs:

Takes two polygons and finds their intersection. If they share a border, returns the border; if they don't intersect, returns undefined.